# I want to search files in diffrent path and make list in another txt file UNIX

Tags: shell, unix

I want to make a unix script in which  search file name in diffrent path and if found save that name in another text file.

I want to make a list of similar file name in diffrent path and save that list in another text file.

My list should append all the name  one after another when similar file name is found.

Eg. `path1 has 
       A B C D files 
 and path2 has 
       A E F D files`

When searching by file name here A AND D is in both then in another text file list of similar file should be save.

HERE `A D` should be in another txt file

Please help

I have made script as per the help i got but its giving unexpected token '('

```
#!/bin/sh

export file1=/home/ay/object_list.txt
export file2=/var/opt/cia/db_extract/object_list.txt

comm -1 -2 <(sort ${file1})<(sort ${file2}) >searchlist.txt
```

But is showing unexpected token
comm -1 -2 <(sort ${file1})<(sort ${file2}) >searchlist.txt
running fine if i run directlt please help

Comment: Does path1 and path2 share a parent directory?

Comment: No diffrent DIRECTORIES.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Original Answer**

Something like this:

```
comm -1 -2 <(cd dir1 && find . -type f | sort) <(cd dir2 && find . -type f|sort)    > file.txt
```

This works as follows. The piece in the first `<(...)` changes to the first directory you specify (dir1) and generates a list of all the files in there and then sorts it. The second `<(...)` produces a similar list for the second directory. The `comm` command then compares the two lists and prints the common entries from the 3rd column, suppressing columns 1 and 2, using `-1 -2`.

**Updated in response to question**

If you already have the two files, you will need to sort them first so that `comm` works properly. So, say you have `list1.txt` and `list2.txt`, you can do this:

```
sort list1.txt > a.txt
sort list2.txt > b.txt
comm -1 -2 a.txt b.txt
```

Or, the following is shorter:

```
comm -1 -2 <(sort list1.txt) <(sort list2.txt)
```

Comment: I already have list of two diffrent files,i want to take out the common file name into another txt file

Comment: I have made script as per the help i got U its giving unexpected token '('

    #!/bin/sh

    export file1=/home/ay/object_list.txt
    export file2=/var/opt/cia/db_extract/object_list.txt
 
    comm -1 -2 <(sort ${file1})<(sort ${file2}) >searchlist.txt


But is showing unexpected token
comm -1 -2 <(sort ${file1})<(sort ${file2}) >searchlist.txt
running fine if i run directlt please help

Comment: Try changing the first line to `#!/bin/bash` rather than `#!/bin/sh` - the `<(...)` is a `bash` extension.

Comment: ... and change `${file1}` to `"$file1"` - likewise for `${file2}`